# why could this happen when downloading file from Internet

Tags: http, google-chrome, https, download

I found an interesting issue that confused me.

I noticed it when I use a *Chrome* to download files from the Internet.

For some kind of files, like [this one](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Handouts/1-Introduction_March28.pdf), the Chrome download bar will remind you the total size of the file and the remaining time to download it.

However, for some other kind of files, like [this one](https://courseware.stanford.edu/mod/file/download.php?file_guid=215025), the chrome download bar will not remind the total size and the remaining time.

So why is there such difference?

I guess it has something with the HTTP or HTTPS protocol, am I right?
But I do not know how to explain this in this point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one has this HTTP header:

```
Content-Length: 19162507
```

The second one does not have the [Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) header, and so the browser cannot show the download percentage.

You can view HTTP headers with `curl` on the command line:

```
curl -I http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Handouts/1-Introduction_March28.pdf
```